# Schema.org 'sameAs' for 2 different types of company web site

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I currently have one generic company web site and one product specific web site (for a product that is not featured on the generic web site). Both sites represent the same company.

I am currently using Schema.org's [`sameAs`](https://schema.org/sameAs) property to associate each web site with its respective social media pages, using the [`Organization`](https://schema.org/Organization) type for both.

I am aware that the product specific web site isn't really an organisation but more a local site for a product name (not a brand). I am wondering if it isn't better and more accurate to just put such one script on the main web site only and have the product specific web site and the product specific social media pages in the same 'sameAs' list along with the generic company social media page links.

Comment: I think the answer is probably to use the `isPartOf` and `hasPart` properties to say that one url or creative work is part of another and vice versa, so in this sense, if a separate web site is run by the same company and uses the same brand but different category of products, then this seems reasonable to use these properties, rather than `sameAs` which might be semantically confusing for crawlers. Does anyone have a different opinion?